# How do I install Ubuntu Desktop from the terminal?

Tags: desktop-environments, raspberrypi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop on a Raspberry Pi 4 4gb, but I can't find any adequate instructions to do so right after installing it on the Pi.

Comment: You can install ubuntu-desktop package: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Does this help? https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-ubuntu-on-raspberry-pi/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=02072020